# How I create a 3D graph in two-file gnuplot

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

I need to create a 3D graph in the gnuplot of two different files with error bar
The first is the file below

```
V   IQR      Error
10 7128.74 258.414 
50 575.114 32.2386 
100 791.114 24.359
```

and the second is this

```
V    TDR    Error
10 590.377 4.08883 
50 599.546 0.177403 
100 599.32 0.338699
```

I wanted something similar to this

[image]

Comment: Please clarify.   A 3D plot with error bars would require 4 (or 5) values for each entry [x y z error_on_z] or [x y z z-low z-high].   Where is your 4th value coming from?

Comment: I.e. Which column of data is your x? which is your y? which is your z? and which column or combination of columns is the error?

Comment: Currently I plot TDR and IQR separately. What I want is to plot in 3D for easy comparison. My table has the X, Y and Z. Z is fixed and.

Comment: OK the file contains x, y, and z.  Where does the error value come from so that we can draw an error bar?    If by "error" you mean the difference between z in file 1 and z in file 2, gnuplot cannot do that. You would have to merge the two files.